# I can get layout from other applications but NOT with image(drawable)

Tags: image, layout, drawable

I'm trying to add a THEME feature in my app protector application but i faced a big problem.

I can get layout from other application but the layout doesn't present the drawable
(ex. Background, Src, ...)
(ex. If i make a theme app with a layout whose background is "background.png", a main app can get a layout of the theme app but with no background!!)

↓↓Code

```
Resources theme = null;

        try
        {
            theme = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(nowTheme);
            //nowTheme = packageName
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {

        }

        if (theme != null)
        {
            int resID = theme.getIdentifier("theme" , "layout", nowTheme);
            mView = mInflater.inflate(theme.getLayout(resID), null);
        }
        else
        {
            mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_default, null);
            dataConverter.dataPut(this, "default", SP_LOCATION_THEME, "theme");
            //dataConverter = sharedpreferences

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", 3000).show();
        }
```

Is there any wrong code i do? :(

p.s I think that's because of "R.drawable" for background of the theme app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the background appears, the layout must declare the background drawable resource in there. Check the layout or post the layout of your theme here.

Comment: how can i declare the background drawable resource?

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution :)

Comment: @namooplus, please, explain me how did you do this. I can't find solution.